# how to read integers from file and write each integer into different name integer?

Tags: c++

This is how the program looks and i need to make all integers with different name. Like x,x1,x2 and so on...

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream iFile("input.txt");        // input.txt has integers, one per line

    while (true) {
    int x;
    iFile >> x;
    if( iFile.eof() ) break;
    cerr << x << endl;

}
 system("Pause");
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Have you learned "array" (or "vector")?

Comment: You need to specify this problem better. I suspect that first you will have to think about it more to understand what to do.

Comment: a little bit about arrays, but vectors never..

Answer (score 4):

Do the names all need to be distinct, or is it acceptable to put the numbers into a collection?  If so, you can do something like this to read in the numbers.

```
vector<int> numbers;
ifstream fin("infile.txt");
int x;
while( fin >> x ) {
    numbers.push_back(x);
}
```

Comment: i need every number to get a different name cause i am about to use them in creating a binary tree.

Comment: As a result of this, you would have integers "named" `numbers[0]`, `numbers[1]`, `numbers[2]` etcetera. I'm putting "named" between quotes here, because the word "name" in C++ usually means something else.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of situation is why arrays were invented. The syntax changes slightly, so you use `x[1]`, `x[2]`, and so on, instead of `x1`, `x2`, and so on, but other than that it's pretty much exactly what you seem to want.

Comment: vectors or array objects are preferable to arrays

Answer (score 0):

If you are associating numbers with names, a `std::map` (an *associative container*), is the data structure to use:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using std::map;
using std::string;
using std::cout;

typedef std::map<string, int> Data_Container;

//...
Data_Container my_container;
//...
my_container["Herman"] = 13;
my_container["Munster"] = 13;
cout << "Herman's number is: " << my_container["Herman"] << "\n";
```

Comment: thanks :) and maybe you can tell me how to write a cycle to search and delete the largest number in vector?